# Get all the dates between two successive dates in same column for a specific group

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a Market table (#Market) like this:

[image]

For each delivery date of a market, I need to generate dates till the next delivery date of that market. The desired output should be as shown below:

[image]

I have tried getting the calendar dates based on maximum and minimum date range for all the markets and then tried matching the dates with the market delivery dates.

The calendar dates (#Calendar) are generated as follows:

```
Date
2020-03-01
2020-03-02
2020-03-03
2020-03-04
2020-03-05
2020-03-06
2020-03-07
2020-03-08
2020-03-09
2020-03-10
2020-03-11
2020-03-12
2020-03-13
2020-03-14
2020-03-15
```

But I could not find a way to compare the calendar table against the Market table and get the dates between the consecutive rows for each delivery date and market. The below cross join gives me all the dates after a sprcific delivery date but could not restrict till the next delivery date for that market.

```
select * from #Calendar c
    cross join #Market  m
    where date>=[Delivery Date]
    order by marketid,[Delivery Date]
```

Is there a way to restrict these dates just before the next delivery date for a specific market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select marketid, deliverydate, deliverydate as date,
             dateadd(day, -1, lead(deliverydate) over (partition by marketid order by deliverydate)) as lastdd
      from #market m
      union all
      select marketid, deliverydate, dateadd(day, 1, date) as date,
             lastdd
      from cte
      where date < lastdd
     )
select marketid, deliverydate, date
from cte;
```

If you can have more than 100 days in-between, then you will need `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I understand it correctly, we are first creating the date before the next delivery date and then adding all the dates in between? Could you please edit the answer to help me understand what is the part of cte here since the query shows join on cte within cte. Also what is nextdd here?

Comment: @AnishaSinghal . . . There is no "join" on the CTE.  This is the answer.

Comment: Hi Gordon, could you please explain what value nextdd stores? That is the only place where I am getting error.

Comment: @AnishaSinghal . . . The code has `lastdd` which is the last date for the current delivery date/market combination.  It is the next delivery date for the market (if any) minus one day.

Comment: If nextdd is next delivery date, then should the solution be this?                  ```lead([Delivery Date]) over (partition by DeliveryLocationID order by [Delivery date]) as nextdd```    in the nextdd column

Comment: @AnishaSinghal . . . No, the issue is the `date` and `deliverydate` columns -- I had them swapped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208862/discussion-between-anisha-singhal-and-gordon-linoff).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there are no more than 1000 days gap the following should work

```
with row_gen
  as (select top 1000 row_number() over(order by name)-1 as rnk
        from master..spt_values
     )
    ,dates
      as(
        select a.marketid,a.delivery_date,case when lead(a.delivery_date) over(partition by marketid order by delivery_date asc) is null then 
                                                    dateadd(day,1,a.delivery_date)
                                               else lead(a.delivery_date) over(partition by marketid order by delivery_date asc) 
                                           end as next_val
          from dbo.t a
         )
select *,dateadd(day,b.rnk,a.delivery_date)
  from dates a
  join row_gen b
    on dateadd(day,b.rnk,a.delivery_date)<a.next_val
```